# how to play mp3 in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm going to play MP3 in my ASP.NET web app (VS 2008), I want user to have a nice GUI for play/pause/stop and selecting different musics. Is there any way to start playing music automatically at site start up? Of course music should not be restarted after a new page is being loaded, is there any way I can control music via server side code?

thanks, I've tested many players but I think I need more sources

Comment: This is nothing to do with ASP.NET. It's an HTML/Javascript/other issue really.

Comment: Server-side generates client-side(HTML5) which controls the audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Music media can be played using HTML5 or Flash.  These are front-end technologies.  You can, of course, 'fetch' urls and files using back-end asp.net code.

There are a few javascript libraries out there that will determine if a user has an HTML5 browser and if not, use Flash as a backup.

One of them I like to use is called jPlayer, for jQuery.

http://jplayer.org/

Comment: Good answer to a poorly written question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/MP3PlayerControl.aspx) Server Control or you cane check [these](http://www.aspnetaudio.com) resources